# TableView duplicating images?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function in my code which fetches images from firebase it does all that correctly however it duplicates the 2 images (in this case) its fetching.

**Edit**: (This bellow is likely not the case, I believe it is something else just based off the fact that trying multiple seemingly valid fixes did not fix the problem).

It seems this arrises due to the placement of `self.tableView.reloadData()` However I have experimented with many placements all are failing.

```
    func fetchAllUsersImages() {
        print("inside func")
        self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
                if let snapShotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
                for (_, value) in snapShotValue {
                    print(value)

                    if let imageURL = URL(string: value) {
                            print(imageURL, "image url here")
                            do {
                                let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                                let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                                let ImageObject = Image()
                                ImageObject.image = image
                                self.arrayOfImgObj.append(ImageObject)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            } catch {
                                print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            print("hfjdsaklhjfksahalh")
        })
        print(arrayOfImgObj.count)
    }
```

Here is the output from the console:

```
     Description:  post1 
Description:  oosJPm4MEnWWis5p7p1unCbZxQH3
 inside func 0 Optional({
        image1 = "https://URLIsHere";
        image2 = "https://URLIsHere"; 
}) 
https://URLIsHere 
https://URLIsHere image url here 
https://URLIsHere 
https://URLIsHere image url here
hfjdsaklhjfksahalh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the bellow TableViewDataSource method:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrayOfImgObj.count
}
```

After deleting this the code should work properly. I am not sure why this works, If you do just leave a comment bellow so we can know.